# How can I use HCE mode, or even SE?

Tags: nfc, tizen, hce

I have an RFID Card Reader, and whenever I approach my Tizen-based watch to it, it reports a constant ID code of `AABBCCDD`.

I'm trying to create a (preferrably service-) app, which emulates my RFID card, to let the reader read `11223344` when I approach the watch to it.

I have read various Tizen articles, and codes, here is my closest trial with some results:

```
nfc_manager_is_supported -> Yes
nfc_manager_initialize -> Success
nfc_se_get_card_emulation_mode -> NFC_SE_CARD_EMULATION_MODE_ON
nfc_manager_set_hce_event_cb -> Success but no events are coming at all
nfc_manager_set_se_event_cb -> Success but only NFC_SE_EVENT_FIELD_ON and NFC_SE_EVENT_FIELD_OFF events are coming
nfc_manager_get_se_type -> NFC_SE_TYPE_ESE
nfc_manager_set_se_transaction_event_cb(NFC_SE_TYPE_ESE..) -> Success but no events at all
nfc_se_set_preferred_handler -> Success
```

I have a "myrfid.xml" in `/shared/res":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application name="org.example.nfcserviceapp">
   <wallet>
      <aid-group category="other">
         <aid aid="11223344"
              se_type="hce" unlock="false" power="sleep"/>
      </aid-group>
   </wallet>
</application>
```

But I think I misunderstood something, as it's not working, and I have no idea on what is this "wallet" section means.

Is this AID meant to be my card's ID at all?

How can I make this Tizen-based watch to send my desired code instead of its own? This should be possible via Host-based Card Emulation feature which is supported by this watch.

But the lack of documentation makes it very hard to reach.

I'm on **Tizen 5.5.0.2**

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once, I do not know what your RFID Card Reader is, and I also do not know what Communication in this Reader and Watch.
For this reason, I do not know what you say certain constant ID, "AABBCCDD" exactly.
That may be the result of communictaion with SmartCard in SE and reader, or it just may be the SE Hardware ID. (or something even I don't know)

If "AABBCCDD" is derived as a result of communication with certain Smartcard in SE,
it is difficult to change this value. That's because, In order to replace the applet (smartcard) in the eSE mounted on the watch, it is necessary to contact the Samsung B2B channel, not the application implementation.

If "AABBCCDD" is derived as a result of GET DATA COMMAND (FF CA 00 00 00) of ISO 7816-4, it is also difficult to change this value. It is not information that can change.

Anyway, to communicate with RFID Card Reader and your Application,
the RFID Card Reader should send a SELECT FILE COMMAND to the WATCH.

First, you have no problem with your wallet.xml file and each API call result.
Try sending the following command to Watch in your RFID CARD Reader.

Select command (00 A4 04 00) | Length (04) | AID (11 22 33 44)

00 A4 04 00 04 11 22 33 44

In this case, your application should be launched and the HCE Event Callback should be called.
Please check the result after confirming that part.
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Thanks, I have no access to RFID reader. It does what it does, I have no information regarding that. I can only see it's output as Wiegand, and it reports "AABBCCDD" when I approach the watch to it.